# Is there better way to do this without duplicating queries?

Tags: plugin-development, terms

I'm building a plugin to show message based on which category user is browsing.
For that I want to get all categories and I'm getting all categories by running:

```
$all_categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => false ));
$all_category_ids = array();
foreach($all_categories as $category)
{       
    array_push($all_category_ids, $category->term_id);    
}
```

Then I'm getting sub categories which I want to hide using:

```
$exclude_categories = get_categories(array( 'child_of' => 55, 'hide_empty' => false ));
$exclude_category_ids = array();    
foreach($exclude_categories as $ex_cat)
{
    array_push($exclude_category_ids, $ex_cat->term_id); 
}
```

Then I'm getting the difference by:

```
$to_show = array_diff($all_category_ids,$exclude_category_ids)
```

This gets the job done but query monitor plugin showing that there is duplicate queries which i have by running `get_categories()` twice.

Is there better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your first `get_categories` call will load *all* terms into memory, you can just loop over 'em and check if they have an ancestor with ID `55`, and WordPress won't ever hit the db again:

```
$terms = get_terms([
     'taxonomy'   => 'category',
     'hide_empty' => false,
]);

foreach ( $terms as $k => $term ) {
    if ( in_array( 55, get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'category', 'taxonomy' ) ) )
        unset( $terms[ $k ] );
}
```